# Arm Template SendGrid - maximum number of allowed accounts was reached

Tags: azure, sendgrid, azure-rm-template

I am deploying an ARM template with the following SendGrid asset:

```
{
  "name": "[variables('sendgridAccountName')]",
  "type": "Sendgrid.Email/accounts",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "apiVersion": "2015-01-01",
  "plan": {
    "name": "free",
    "publisher": "Sendgrid",
    "product": "sendgrid_azure",
    "promotionCode": ""
  },
  "properties": {
    "password": "[parameters('emailPassword')]",
    "acceptMarketingEmails": "0",
    "firstname": "",
    "lastname": "",
    "email": ""
  }
}
```

which fails with the following error message:

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 14:39:58 - Resource Sendgrid.Email/accounts 'motherstaging' failed with message '{
  "error": {
    "code": "AccountLimitReached",
    "message": "The maximum number of allowed accounts was reached."
  }
}'
At D:\Work\ExcelWraps\src\Deploy\ManualDeploy.ps1:113 char:5
+     New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name ((Get-ChildItem $templat ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet
```

I have previously deployed several of these, this is in a new resource group without any SendGrids. I can't find any information about this error on the internet. What does the message mean, why does it occur and what can I do about it?

Comment: probably what it says? too many registered accounts? try deleting some old ones?

Comment: What accounts, where?

Comment: sendgrid accounts in azure. you are creating those, right? :)

Comment: I need to add 1 send grid to a resource group which currently has none. Which one am I going to delete?

Comment: check all sendgrid resources you have in all subscriptions

Comment: Where is the documentation on this that stipulates a maximum number? Check against what value? What is the maximum, please quote your sources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: you've reached the maximum number of (free) SendGrid accounts under your subscription:

> You are limited to 1 SendGrid accounts per Azure subscription. This limit exists for security and compliance reasons to prevent abuse.

Source: [SendGrid documentation](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/partners/microsoft-azure/) under **Still have questions?**

If you really need more than one SendGrid account, think about opening another Azure subscription to accommodate it.

Comment: Note: This has now dropped to 1 account per subscription.